# question on h2o hanging when attempting to slice rows

Tags: python, h2o

I have I guess a moderately sized dataframe of ~500k rows and 200 columns with 8GB of memory.

My problem is that when I got to slice my data, even very small sized datasets when this gets trimmed down to 6k rows and 200 columns, that it just hangs and hangs for 10/15 min+.   Then if I hit the STOP button for python interactive and re-try the process happens in 2-3 seconds.

I don't know why I can do my row-slicing in this 2-3 seconds normally. It is making it impossible to run programs as things just hang and hang and have to be manually stopped before it works.

I am following the approach laid out on the h2o webpage:

```
import h2o
h2o.init()

# Import the iris with headers dataset
path = "http://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/smalldata/iris/iris_wheader.csv"
df = h2o.import_file(path=path)

# Slice 1 row by index
c1 = df[15,:]
c1.describe

# Slice a range of rows
c1_1 = df[range(25,50,1),:]
c1_1.describe

# Slice using a boolean mask. The output dataset will include rows with a sepal length
# less than 4.6.
mask = df["sepal_len"] < 4.6
cols = df[mask,:]
cols.describe

# Filter out rows that contain missing values in a column. Note the use of '~' to
# perform a logical not.
mask = df["sepal_len"].isna()
cols = df[~mask,:]
cols.describe
```

The error message from the console is as follows.  I have this same error message repeated several times.:

```
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h2o/expr.py in (.0)
    149             return self._cache._id  # Data already computed under ID, but not cached
    150         assert isinstance(self._children,tuple)
--> 151         exec_str = "({} {})".format(self._op, " ".join([ExprNode._arg_to_expr(ast) for ast in self._children]))
    152         gc_ref_cnt = len(gc.get_referrers(self))
    153         if top or gc_ref_cnt >= ExprNode.MAGIC_REF_COUNT:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/h2o/expr.py in _arg_to_expr(arg)
    161             return "[]"  # empty list
    162         if isinstance(arg, ExprNode):
--> 163             return arg._get_ast_str(False)
    164         if isinstance(arg, ASTId):
```

Comment: So, when you cancel and run it again it works fine? It sounds like it could be working, but not sending the success message back, for some reason. Try having flow (127.0.0.1:54321) open, and check memory available just before and after you run the problem line. There might be some other clues in there as to what is happening.

Comment: hi @DarrenCook thank you for taking time to respond.  I actually tried going down to even way smaller datasets of just like 4000 and 50 rows. I don't think memory would be a problem since this is only thing running and im doing 8Gb as the size when I use init.  I can also load up 5-6x (stopped trying after this) of a original massive dataset separately.   The problem just originates when I row slice.  Yes, when I cancel it instantly works again.  The message  "Data already computed under ID, but not cached" shows up maybe 6-7x (not sure). I'm stuck! I've waited 20min and no luck. 3.28.0.1